# How do I upgrade to 16.04 with Ubuntu Gnome 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I use Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS, and I'm wondering if I can safely upgrade to 16.04 LTS.

Do I just click upgrade on the software upgrade utility, or should I run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

The last time I tried to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 LTS, my computer complained and gave me no end of issues.

Comment: I have a different distro.

Comment: Just so you're aware, `apt-get dist-upgrade` does *not* actually upgrade your OS version. It will only run additional dependency management and make sure no packages are held back (e.g. when a package like the kernel wants new packages installed). You might be thinking of `do-release-upgrade`, which is called by the software update GUI.

Comment: What's the command to upgrade the OS?

Comment: @Costa: Same principle irrespective of the flavor.

Comment: @Costa it will still work the exact same use `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Since 16.04.1, all official Ubuntu flavors (including Ubuntu GNOME) are updateable from 14.04.

Comment: What is "it?" The other command, or the upgrade to LTS 16.04 event though I'm running Gnome Ubuntu?

Comment: Will I need to reinstall a bunch of my software? Neovim? Skype and so on?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. It tries to keep as much software as possible.

Comment: @Costa No you will keep the same software and it refers to your distribution/OS/Computer basically saying you can upgrade the same way with any *Buntu flavor